# Google Script: How to CopyRows from one sheet to another spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to copy rows from one sheet to another spreadhsheet using google sciprt but the same is not working.

Please could you help me or explain me how to do this works?

```
   function CopyRows() {
    var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXX');
    var sourcesheet = source.getSheetByName('sheet1');

    var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('YYYYY')
    var targetsheet = target.getSheetByName('sheet1');
    var targetrange = targetsheet.getRange(targetsheet.getLastRow() + 1 , 1);
    sourcesheet.getRange(2, 1, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), sourcesheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetrange);

   }
```

Do you know if exist anyway to copy rows from one sheet to another sheet in other spreadsheet?

Best Regards

---

## EDIT: 01/07/2013

Thanks PhysLabTsar , your script works very well for copyrows from one sheet to other spreadsheet.

```
   function myFunction() {
     var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxx');
       var sourcesheet = source.getSheetByName('sheet1');

       var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxx')
       var targetsheet = target.getSheetByName('sheet1');
var targetrange = targetsheet.getRange(2, 1, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), sourcesheet.getLastColumn());
       var rangeValues = sourcesheet.getRange(2, 1, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), sourcesheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
       targetrange.setValues(rangeValues);
```

}

---

EDIT: CopyRows from Multiples Sheets

```
   function ShellCopyValues(){
     var sheets = ['sheet1','sheet2','sheet3','sheet4','sheet4'];
     for (var s in sheets){
   CopyRows(sheets[s]);
     }
   }

   function CopyRows(uname) {
     var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXX');
       var sourcesheet = source.getSheetByName(uname);

       var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('YYYYYY')
       var targetsheet = target.getSheetByName(uname);
       var targetrange = targetsheet.getRange(2, 1, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), sourcesheet.getLastColumn());
       var rangeValues = sourcesheet.getRange(2, 1, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), sourcesheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
       targetrange.setValues(rangeValues);

   }
```

If anyone have a best way to do it. Please feelfree to letme know.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem is the `copyTo()` method. That only works when the target is in the same spreadsheet. To fix this you can grab the range that you want from the `initial` spreadsheet and use `getValues()` to store them in an object `ARRAY`. Then open up your `final` spreadsheet and grab a same size range and use `setValues()` to dump them. The size of the `final` range must match the size of the `initial` range.

Here is something that should work:

```
function myFunction() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxx');
    var sourcesheet = source.getSheetByName('sheet1');

    var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxx')
    var targetsheet = target.getSheetByName('sheet1');
    var targetrange = targetsheet.getRange(2, 1, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), sourcesheet.getLastColumn());
    var rangeValues = sourcesheet.getRange(2, 1, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), sourcesheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    targetrange.setValues(rangeValues);

}
```

I hope this helps. This is my first answer in this place, so I'm sure there is a better way that someone else knows about. But it is the way I've been using. :)

Comment: You can offset the values in the `final` spreadsheet after using the `setValues()` method. The important part is that the dimensions of the `final` range, or in your case `targetrange`, must match the `rangeValues`'s dimension.

Comment: Thanks So much... Now is working.... How can I get this work for multples sheet. I mean copy sheet 1 to Sheet 1, sheet 2 to sheet2, sheet 3 to sheet3...

Comment: Sorry, I got a bit busy to come back and login here. But I'm glad you found your answer you were seeking. :)

Comment: yes, it's not possible copy rows between different spreadsheet. I use getvalues. If possible getvalues with format?